# mongo DB illegal syntax

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Here's an example of my data:

```
{"CAND_NAME": "WARREN, ELIZABETH", "CAND_PTY_AFFILIATION": "DEM", "CAND_OFFICE_ST":"MA","CONNECTED_ORG_NM": null, "cmte_received":
{"CAND_NAME": "WARREN, ELIZABETH", "CAND_PTY_AFFILIATION": "DEM", "CAND_OFFICE_ST":"MA","CONNECTED_ORG_NM": null, "cmte_received":
```

I'm trying to find the top five `cmte_received` by transaction amount and here's my code:

```
db.Contrib_Data.aggregate({ $group: {$“cmte_received”},
                       totalcontri : { $sum : $"TRANSACTION_AMT" } } ,{ $sort: {totalcontri: -1},{$limit: 5})
```

It kept giving me a syntax error due to an illegal character.

Comment: Yep, `{$“cmte_received”}` and `$"TRANSACTION_AMT"` aren't vaild JS object and string. Probably 1st can be corrected to  `{_id: "$cmte_received"}` if you would like to group by `cmte_received`. And second to `"$TRANSACTION_AMT"` to be valid string. Also, docs usually helpful for me while doing aggregations: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/

Answer (score 0):

You are using `$group` pipeline without `_id`, so first, you should go through the official documentation of [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#group-aggregation) and also you are not passing the values `{$“cmte_received”}` and `$"TRANSACTION_AMT"` in correct formate it should be as `{"$cmte_received"}` and `"$TRANSACTION_AMT"`.

Your query with appropriate pipeline should be as below:

```
db.Contrib_Data.aggregate(
    { 
        $group: 
        { 
            _id: "$cmte_received", 
            "totalcontri" : {  $sum : "$TRANSACTION_AMT"  } 
        }
    }, 
    { 
        $sort: 
        { "totalcontri": -1 }
    }, 
    {
        $limit:5
    }  
)
```

I also advise you to go through the pipeline stages of MongoDB [Aggregation Pipeline Stages](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/#aggregation-pipeline-stages)